# Reserving a domestic TGV train in Germany

Tags: germany, france, high-speed-rail, sncf, deutsche-bahn

I am travelling to Germany and France next month. For the last leg, I am travelling from Lyon to Paris Charles de Gaulle Terminal 2 by TGV.

Would it be possible to reserve this ticket in Germany(Frankfurt, Munchen, Dusseldorf, Koln, Bonn, or Stuttgart)?

Also, would this(buying 2 weeks in advance) be cheaper than buying the ticket 6 days in advance?

Comment: How about booking it online on voyages sncf?

Comment: And [the link](https://uk.voyages-sncf.com/en/#/)

Comment: @JoErNanO thing is, my parents have a South Korean debit card(I am South Korean), and payment requires verification by a Korean phone number, which we don't have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have posed your question to the service team of Deutsche Bahn on Twitter, and the [answer is *yes*](https://twitter.com/DB_Bahn/status/878263406339477505).

> Q: Kann man von DB-Bahnhöfen aus TGV-Tickets kaufen? [...]
>
> A: Ja, das geht. Am besten geht er in ein DB Reisezentrum. /jn

Translation (by me):

> Q: Is it possible to buy TGV tickets at DB train stations? [...]
>
> A: Yes, that's possible. It would be best if he went to a DB Reisezentrum (DB travel service center) [to buy a TGV ticket in Germany]. /jn

You can use [this search engine](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/ff/query.exe/dn?filialfinder=1) to find a Reisezentrum near one of your way points on your Germany trip. Put in a City you'll be staying at and look at the *Reisezentrum* section in the results. Without looking, I'd bet that all the cities you mentioned are big enough that at least their main stations provide a Reisezentrum.

A Reisezentrum usually accepts most payment methods, like cash, european debit cards (Maestro/EC) and common credit cards.

Comment: I have arrived in Frankfurt and reserved the ticket. Thank you!!

Comment: @Yubin ah, have a nice stay :)